# Pi Day Celebration Ideas?

Tags: undergraduate-education, secondary-education, primary-education

I realize it is probably a little late seeing as Pi Day is tomorrow.. but for the future, or late celebrations on Monday, what are some things that you do with your students for Pi Day (any grade level)?

Comment: 3/14/15 at 9:26:53am in whatever timezone...

Comment: NCTM has been sending out lots of stuff, in case you are a member (or thinking about joining). Viewing some of the material requires membership, but you might be able to find parts by googling; [**here**](http://i.imgur.com/0HCouGx.jpg) is a screenshot of their recent email.

Comment: Make them understand Pi. :)

Answer (score 4):

Here at the university level, we had a social gathering served with quite a large quantity of pie and a speaker who gave a talk to the department colloquium and to the math club. We ended up doing this yesterday (Thursday prior) as Pi Day is Saturday and it is also spring break. We do this every year and have a great turn out amongst graduate students and faculty.

Answer (score 4):

The student AMS chapter here in MN had a pizza party, and (through whatever chain of causality) asked me to give a talk... and I chose to "ramp it up" by talking about "failing to prove the Riemann Hypothesis"...

... which, if one knows about various events, can be a substantive, non-trivial story. And, yes, people've not given up on the issue, although obviously young-ish people oughtn't pin their careers to such a thing...

But, as it happens, I had/have some not-completely-trivial things to say about trying-if-only-to-fail in this case, ... and I did the dramatized-for-general-audience version.

Point: math can have broad appeal if we manage to forget about its dubious (awful) use as filter/weeder for other academic disciplines. Yes, indeed, this hatchet-man function does allow large math departments... but, srsly, folks, we should try to offer something better! Fun! Math should be fun! Not just a prank...

"Don't get me started..." :)

Answer (score -2):

Instruct students to create drawings that incorporate memes using words beginning with the syllable "pi." This activity offers an engaging combination of language —focusing on word selection—)and visual art(whether through traditional hand-drawing or the use of generative AI technologies) the collective work can compose a book. one example ( have much ore in Portuguese:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

this activity is specially convinient for multilianguage classes.